# Цикл поиска в тексте не работает

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста почему цикл не работает, хотя я вроде-бы все правильно сделал?
text = We@lcome

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ffrgrgrthtr
{
class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int c=0;
        int i=0;
        char lin = '@';
        
        string path = @"C:\MyTest2.txt";
        string text = File.ReadAllText(path);
        
          for ( c = 0; c < text.Length; i++)
 {
    if (text[c] == lin)
    {   int y =c;
    if (c>0)
        {   if (text[c-1]=='e')
        {if (text[c-2]=='W')
            {String modified = text.Insert(y+1, "36`"); 
                    Console.WriteLine(modified); }}}}}
     Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что такое "не работает"? Цикл никогда не заканчивается?

```
for ( c = 0; c < text.Length; c++)
                              ^ <-- !!!
```

Comment: Property or indexer 'string.Length' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only (CS0200) - C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\ffrgrgrthtr\ffrgrgrthtr\Program.cs:27,25

Comment: @user464537 В коде вопроса нет этого места.